# How to create a new hashtable from an array and another hashtable

Tags: arrays, powershell

I want to add keys and values to a new hashtable from an array and another hashtable. With my code I'm able to add the hashtable values as new keys but I'm not able to add each array element as new values. I'm trying to access each array element by using a variable as the index number but PowerShell does not allow this. Is there another way of doing this?

```
$targetFile = "C:\test\Target.xml"
$targetFile = [xml](Get-Content $targetFile)

$IPlookup = @{}

$targetFile.Deployment.Target | Foreach {
$IPlookup.Add($_.hostname, $_.IP)
}

$targetList = @()

$targetList = "C:\Target 1\database","C:\Target 2\database"

$deployList = @{}

X=0

$IPlookup.Keys | foreach{
$deployList.Add($_, $targetList[X])
X += 1
}

$deployList | Out-File C:\Temp\DeployList.txt

# I would like the HashTable to have this information:
# Key            Value        
# 192.168.1.10   C:\Target 1\database
# 192.168.1.11   C:\Target 2\database
```

Comment: I added content to the array and explained the output I'm looking for. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The code seems fine except the final `$deployList | Out-file` because hashtables are not directly enumerable. Use something like ```$deployList.GetEnumerator() | %{ $_.name + "`t" + $_.value } | out-file C:\Temp\DeployList.txt```